# When did Clara hold a sword?

Tags: doctor-who

In *The Girl Who Died* when The Doctor asked who had held a sword in combat before only Clara and himself had their hands up.

I remember that in *The Christmas Invasion* The Doctor held a sword when he challenged the Sycorax leader but i don't remember when, if ever, Clara held one in combat.

So when did Clara hold a sword in combat before?

Comment: There are lots of Doctor Who adventures we don't get to watch on TV.

Comment: Don't forget the whole "impossible girl" arc. One of those versions of Clara could well have held a sword.

Comment: I seem to recall her using Madam vastra (I think that's her name, the Silurian Victorian detective woman)'s once - though granted it might have been one of those other Claras so idk if it counts. I'll try and dig it up later, but does that ring a bell to anyone else 'cause its a vague enough memory I might be imagining it haha?

Comment: @MacCooper I thought so too (*Deep Breath* maybe?), but couldn't find the relevant clip to check.

Answer (score 10):

Not exactly a sword, but she was holding a **medieval weapon** in battle during series 7 episode 12, *Nightmare in Silver*:

[image: mace]

And (as already mentioned by Slicey) another medieval weapon in this image from series 8 episode 4, *Robot of Sherwood*:

[image: axe]

Comment: +1. The first medieval weapon is a [Morningstar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morning_star_(weapon)) and the second one appears to be a [Halberd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halberd)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible she was battling with a sword in one of her many "fragments" during the doctor's life. But it is also possible she counted the one time she was (trying) to swing that huge axe in Robot of Sherwood.

Answer (score 2):

Just remember that the majority of the Doctor's adventures aren't actually shown. We see many times, the Doctor and his companion running into the TARDIS after doing some unknown thing, running away from something. The Doctor also mentions many adventures that he has had that we never actually saw.

Answer (score 2):

She wields a <s>sword</s> ski-pole in [Doctor Who: The Twelfth Doctor #2.](http://titan-comics.com/c/113-doctor-who-the-twelfth-doctor/)

[image]

The Doctor then offers to give her 'fencing lessons'

[image]

We also see her with swords in [Doctor Who: The Twelfth Doctor #5](http://titan-comics.com/c/241-doctor-who-the-twelfth-doctor/), wielding the titular "*Swords of Kali*"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could have not been when she was with the Doctor because he seems to question her if it is true.  Even if it is a previous incarnation of the Doctor the current Doctor would still have the knowledge that it was true.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps. But can you tell when she *did* hold a sword?

Comment: It could still have been after she started travelling with the Doctor, even if it wasn't when he was actually by her side and could see her.